# Uncaught Error: Type MatFormField does not have 'ɵmod' property

Tags: angular, angular-material-6

I use angular materials for ionic angular app . Does anybody know what this error is ?
I need date range picker to have in app and prefer to be style customizable . Is there any other alternatives to angular material ? Or how to fix this error?

```html
<mat-form-field appearance="fill">
    <mat-label>Enter a date range</mat-label>
    <mat-date-range-input [rangePicker]="picker">
        <input matStartDate placeholder="Start date">
        <input matEndDate placeholder="End date">
    </mat-date-range-input>
    <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
    <mat-date-range-picker #picker></mat-date-range-picker>
</mat-form-field>
```

this is the code

the same error occures with ng-bootstrap's   datepicker